# Proving that log(n+1) is O(log(n). If true, find C and K

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

If I am not mistaken $\log(n+1)$ is $O(\log(n))$ since $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\log(x+1)}{\log(x)}) = 1$

But I don't know how to find $C$ and $K$. Can someone show me how?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are the definitions of C and K? Please be more precise

Comment: If x > K --> f(x) < C * g(x), where f(x)=log(x+1) and g(x)=log(x)

Answer (score 2):

$\log (n+1)\leq C \log (n)$ iff $n+1 \leq n^{C}$. Since $n+1 \leq 2n \leq n^{2}$ for $n \geq 2$ we see that $\log (n+1)\leq 2\log (n)$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Is C=2 and K=2 also for the case where log(n^2) is O(log(n))?

Comment: For this you can even take $C=2,K=1$. Note that $\log (n^{2})$ is nothing but $2 \log n$. @ukqueenforever

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)
=\ln(1+1/n)
\lt 1/n$
so
$\ln(n+1)
=\ln(n)+O(1/n)
=O(\ln(n))
$
since
$\ln(n) = o(n)
$.